# Angular : How to load external library from Bower (not available in NPM)

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, bower, angular-cli

i wanna use a librairy which i got from a **bower** repo .

Since ***it's not available in NPM*** , i wanna know how may it get it work and configure it within my app , my structure looks like this :

[image]

I have tried to deal it like any other library by typing

```
import * as DX from 'bower_components/xtrareportsjs';
```

and i have tried to add it as a script  in the **index.html** OR the **angular-cli.json** scripts' part:

```
<script src="bower_components/xtrareportsjs/report-designer.js"></script>
```

but that didn't recognoze it in all of those case.

**NB** : i wanna reutilize my file (**like jQuery**) not just excecute it

I found old explications , about importation under system.JS but as you can see it's not my case.

**Suggestions ??**

Comment: Did you look into [Global scripts](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to use `jquery` just go to your `angular-cli.json file` then import path of your desired library inside the  `scripts` 
Please check the photo below:
[image]

And then use it on your component like this

```
declare var $: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-navigation',
    templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css']
})
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {

     constructor(){}

     ngOnInit(){
       console.log($('#myElement'));
     }
 }
```