# jQuery not working in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have tried running the following npm install but it doesnt fix anything.
 npm install jquery --save 
 npm install @types/jquery --save-dev

I have added  "scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"],  in .angular-cli.json file.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var $:any;


@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

title = 'jQuery works!';


       onToggle(){

$('.test').slideToggle();

       }

}
```

Error: $ is not defined

Comment: Don't you need import $ from 'jquery'; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511788/how-to-import-jquery-to-angular2-typescrypt-projects

Comment: Do you use bootstrap?

Comment: I helped someone few days ago. please check the link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45440350/angular-how-to-load-external-library-from-bower-not-available-in-npm/45441017#45441017

Comment: Did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try import jquery like this?

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```